# How can I use data_type in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

1. Is there any way to use column data type in where clause in Oracle SQL? My table contains columns with different data types and, as a result, I want to have only columns with 'char' data type.
2. I need to check, whether at least 1 value in every column is set to 'T'. Is there better way to check this, than using if statment?

Thank you for help.

**EDIT**

To be more specific, I add simple table to represent the problem.

Moreover, as I said, there are more columns, including some date columns. Let's say, that user has both

```
+----------+------------+------+------+--------+----------+--------+
| Datatype | Privileges | Open | Edit | Delete | Download | Upload |
+----------+------------+------+------+--------+----------+--------+
| PNG      | Default    | T    | T    | T      | T        | T      |
| JPEG     | Default    | T    | T    | T      | T        | T      |
| PDF      | Default    | T    | F    | F      | T        | T      |
| DOCX     | Default    | T    | T    | F      | T        | T      |
| PNG      | Test       | T    | F    | F      | T        | F      |
| PDF      | Test       | T    | F    | F      | T        | F      |
+----------+------------+------+------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Moreover, as I said, there are more columns, including some date columns. Let's say, that user has both privileges. I need to check, which datatype user has access to and what can he do with each. I.e this user can work with `PNG` file and execute every kind of operation, because of `Default` privileges. `Test` privileges offers some operations on `PNG` file too, but not every o them. This is like bit `OR` operation I assume. If at least one is set to `T`, then user can work with file using set operation. There is more datatypes, privileges and columns, this is just simple example.

I suppose, that there is no fast way to find only `CHAR` columns, so I have to simply write every column in `Select`.

Comment: You would need to use `execute immediate`.

Comment: This sounds like a very strange task or a very bad datamodel. Usually one knows exactly what columns to work with. Why would I select all rows from, say, a product table where one of its char columns equals 'T' (all "boolean" colums containing true, I suppose?)? What could such a result possible tell me (e.g. all products that are in stock or are for women or are environtment-friendly or allowed for under-ages)? Doesn't seem to make sense. Apart from that, build the query dynamically, for instance with PL/SQL.

Comment: I have a table with privileges to access certain operations. Every row contains one type of privileges in connection with one type of attachment and columns define, what kind of operations are possible to do with selected one. Appart from columns with true/false value, there are columns with string, date or numeric values too. My task is to check what user, which have got number of privileges, can do with attachments. I.e. there is a .png file, user has got user and admin privileges and I need to check, whether he can open and delete that kind of file.

Comment: But you know which of the columns are T/F, surely, so you can just name and check them all explicitly? (If they are all not-nullable and constrained to only allow T/F, you could perhaps use `greatest()` to simplify the query a bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex Poole has a good comment--if you already know which columns contain the `T/F` data, there is no need to query by data type, since you already would know which columns to check by name.  You can just query by column name.

I'll provide an answer in case you do **Not** already know which columns will need to be checked but will include far below an example of static sql as well.  I'm not sure exactly what is meant by your second requirements, so I'll add a couple examples that take different angles.  These will use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, as Gordon Linoff mentioned in a comment.

This first example interprets your requirements that you don't know the  table beforehand (otherwise you can just check its `CHAR` colums and query those directly), but want to check whether at least one row has a `T` for each of a given `TABLE`'s `CHAR` columns (across rows).

The block takes a `TABLE_NAME` as a parameter, then builds a dynamic query that checks whether each `COLUMN` has at least one entry in the table with a value of `T`.

First create a test table with different data types including some `CHAR`:

```
CREATE TABLE HETEROGENEOUS (
  CHAR_COL_1      CHAR(10),
  NUMBER_COL_1    NUMBER,
  CHAR_COL_2      CHAR(10),
  TIMESTAMP_COL_1 TIMESTAMP,
  CHAR_COL_3      CHAR(10)
);
```

Then add some test data.  This first load has two of three columns with at least one `T` value, so will fail the test.

```
INSERT INTO HETEROGENEOUS VALUES ('Chewbacca', 1, 'VOLTRON', SYSTIMESTAMP, 'Gundam');
INSERT INTO HETEROGENEOUS VALUES ('T', 1, 'Frodo', SYSTIMESTAMP, 'Starscream');
INSERT INTO HETEROGENEOUS VALUES ('X', 1, 'Bombadil', SYSTIMESTAMP, 'T');
```

Then run the block.  This block counts the number of `CHAR` columns, then executes a dynamic query to count how many columns have at least one row with a `T` value in each `CHAR` column and compares the count of `T` columns with the count of `CHAR` columns:

```
DECLARE
  V_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(128) := 'HETEROGENEOUS';
  V_SQL_TEXT VARCHAR2(32000);
  V_REQUIRED_COLUMN_COUNT NUMBER := 0;
  V_OK_COLUMN_COUNT NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''%s'' AND DATA_TYPE = ''CHAR''',V_TABLE_NAME)
  INTO V_REQUIRED_COLUMN_COUNT;

  SELECT 'SELECT ' ||LISTAGG('(SELECT COALESCE(MIN(1),0) FROM '||V_TABLE_NAME||' WHERE TRIM('||
                             COLUMN_NAME||') = ''T'' AND ROWNUM = 1)','+')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) || ' FROM DUAL'
  INTO V_SQL_TEXT
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = V_TABLE_NAME
        AND DATA_TYPE = 'CHAR' GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL_TEXT INTO V_OK_COLUMN_COUNT;

  IF V_OK_COLUMN_COUNT < V_REQUIRED_COLUMN_COUNT
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('Required at least: %s columns to have 1+ T values but only found: %s',TO_CHAR(V_REQUIRED_COLUMN_COUNT),TO_CHAR(V_OK_COLUMN_COUNT)));
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('All: %s CHAR columns have at least one T value',TO_CHAR(V_REQUIRED_COLUMN_COUNT)));
  END IF;

END;
/
```

Result:

```
Required at least: 3 columns to have 1+ T values but only found: 2
```

Then add another row to get the last required `T` value:

```
INSERT INTO HETEROGENEOUS VALUES ('Deckard', 1, 'T', SYSTIMESTAMP, 'Megatron');
```

And run again:

```
All: 3 CHAR columns have at least one T value
```

The static SQL equivalent (if you already know you table/columns) is:

```
SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(1), 0) FROM HETEROGENEOUS
        WHERE TRIM(CHAR_COL_1) = 'T' AND ROWNUM = 1) +
       (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(1), 0) FROM HETEROGENEOUS
        WHERE TRIM(CHAR_COL_2) = 'T' AND ROWNUM = 1) +
       (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(1), 0) FROM HETEROGENEOUS
        WHERE TRIM(CHAR_COL_3) = 'T' AND ROWNUM = 1)
FROM DUAL;
```

If your requirement instead is to find `ROW`s where at least one `CHAR` column has a `T` value, the approach is the same, but the dynamic query is different.

This second example will find all the rows where at least one `CHAR` column has a value of `T` (and just print them):

```
DECLARE

  V_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(128) := 'HETEROGENEOUS';
  V_SQL_TEXT VARCHAR2(32000);
  TYPE REFCURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
  V_REFCURSOR REFCURSOR;
  V_ROWID VARCHAR2(64);
BEGIN

  SELECT 'SELECT ROWID FROM '||V_TABLE_NAME||' WHERE 1 = ANY ( '||LISTAGG('DECODE(TRIM('||COLUMN_NAME||'),''T'',1,0)  ',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID)||')'
  INTO V_SQL_TEXT
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = V_TABLE_NAME
        AND DATA_TYPE = 'CHAR'
  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;

  OPEN V_REFCURSOR FOR V_SQL_TEXT;
  LOOP
    FETCH V_REFCURSOR INTO V_ROWID;
    EXIT WHEN V_REFCURSOR%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('RowId: %s',V_ROWID));
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE V_REFCURSOR;
END;
/
```

Running it gives the three rows that have a T in any `CHAR` column:

```
RowId: AAGKHPAFJAABL49AAB
RowId: AAGKHPAFJAABL49AAC
RowId: AAGKHPAFJAABL49AAD
```

Or alternatively get the single row that has NO `T` values in their `CHAR` columns, by switching from `ANY` to `ALL`:

```
WHERE 1 = ANY

WHERE 1 <> ALL
```

Gives one row:

```
RowId: AAGKHPAFJAABL49AAA
```

The static eqivalent (if you already know your table and don't need to use data type) is:

```
SELECT ROWID
FROM HETEROGENEOUS
WHERE 1 = ANY (DECODE(TRIM(CHAR_COL_1), 'T', 1, 0),
               DECODE(TRIM(CHAR_COL_2), 'T', 1, 0),
               DECODE(TRIM(CHAR_COL_3), 'T', 1, 0));​
```

Comment: Thanks @micnow21 I'll look the update over and follow up

Comment: @micnow21 Your update helps clarify things; thanks for updating.  Since you have known tables & columns, it is usually preferable to use static sql with column names.  Oracle doesn't support selecting/filtering by data type.  If you want to dynamically execute sql by data-type, you'll need to use pl/sql, though in your update, it looks like you're querying between rows rather than at the table/row level.  In the 2nd question, `MAX` is all needed to check for permissions. If you'd like an example of that or an alternative data model that could simplify queries just let me know. Thanks

Comment: I am really thankful for sharing your knowledge, great help! I suppose, that `MAX` function should return last `char` in alphabetical order?

Comment: Thanks @micnow21  Yeah using `MAX` will sort alphabetically, so any `T` across rows will win-out over `F`  when there are multiple privileges.  A tiny example that will give an overall `T/F` per `datatype` could be something like: `SELECT DATATYPE, MAX("OPEN"), MAX("EDIT") FROM THE_TABLE WHERE "PRIVILEGES" IN ('Test','Default') GROUP BY DATATYPE;`  Anyway if any other clarifications/examples would be useful just let me know.  Thanks